# Apply patches saved in external tree, in Buildroot

Tags: linux, package, external, patch, buildroot

I'm using buildroot 2022.08.3 with an external configuration (BR2_EXTERNAL).

I've created a patch directory in my external tree, where I have put all of my .patch there.

How do i tell buildroot to apply patches that are in my external tree?

I'm guessing i have to use the apply-patches.sh script found in support/scripts, but i am a bit lost if i'm honest.

I tried setting BR2_GLOBAL_PATCH_DIR to my patch directory, but after building the image, my patches are not taken in account.